# Trigger en SQL Server no funciona

Tags: sql, trigger, mssql

Tengo el siguiente Trigger en Microsoft SQL Server el cual solo recibe parametros insertados y los inserta en otra tabla. El trigger funciona sin problema alguno:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterAccess] ON [dbo].[CardAccessHistory] AFTER INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @card_id INT = (SELECT Cardholder_ID FROM inserted)
    DECLARE @datetime_access DATETIME = (SELECT Trans_Time FROM inserted)
    DECLARE @type_access VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT ACR_Name FROM inserted) 
    DECLARE @payroll_id VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT EmployeeNumber FROM CardHolders.dbo.Cardholders WHERE CardHolder_ID = @card_id)
    DECLARE @tag VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT Card_Number FROM inserted)

    INSERT INTO table_test (payroll_id, tag, type_access, card_id) VALUES (@payroll_id, @tag, @type_access, @card_id        

    END
```

El problema viene al añadir condiciones al trigger:
**Todas las variables que estan comentadas ya estan previamente probadas y si funcionan**,
**Comente las variables porque el query tiene mas contenido y para hacerlo mas entendible**
el contenido del trigger esta manualmente probado y funciona, a que me refiero a que simulo datos insertados como variables y el query del trigger si funciona y cumple perfectamente las condiciones, el problema viene al activar el trigger no hace nada
¿Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

```
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[AfterAccess]    Script Date: 03/11/2021 11:51:58 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterAccess] ON [dbo].[CardAccessHistory] AFTER INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @card_id INT = (SELECT Cardholder_ID FROM inserted)
DECLARE @datetime_access DATETIME = (SELECT Trans_Time FROM inserted)
DECLARE @type_access VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT ACR_Name FROM inserted) 
DECLARE @payroll_id VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT EmployeeNumber FROM CardHolders.dbo.Cardholders WHERE CardHolder_ID = @card_id)
DECLARE @tag VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT Card_Number FROM inserted)
    IF @type_access LIKE '%Salida%'
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @total_time TIME = (SELECT total_time FROM Attendance WHERE payroll_id = @payroll_id AND CAST(date_attendance AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
            DECLARE @last_type_access_checked VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP (1) ACR_Name FROM CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
            DECLARE @today_date DATE = (SELECT CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ))
            IF @last_type_access_checked LIKE '%Entrada%'
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @last_datetime_access_checked DATETIME = (SELECT TOP(1) Trans_Time FROM CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
                    DECLARE @add_minutes INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, (@last_datetime_access_checked), (@datetime_access)))
                    IF @total_time IS NULL
                        BEGIN
                            DECLARE @minutes_in_time_with_reset_total_time TIME = (DATEADD(MINUTE, (@add_minutes), ('00:00')))
                            INSERT INTO Attendance (payroll_id, tag, date_attendance, total_time) VALUES (
                                @payroll_id, @tag, @today_date, @minutes_in_time_with_reset_total_time
                            )
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            DECLARE @minutes_in_time TIME = (DATEADD(MINUTE, (@add_minutes), (@total_time)))
                            UPDATE Attendance SET total_time = @minutes_in_time WHERE payroll_id = @payroll_id AND CAST(date_attendance AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
                        END
                    END
            ELSE IF @last_type_access_checked IS NULL
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @yestertday_last_type_access_checked VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP (1) ACR_Name FROM CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
                    IF @yestertday_last_type_access_checked LIKE '%Entrada%'
                        BEGIN
                            DECLARE @yesterday_last_datetime_access_checked  DATETIME = (SELECT TOP(1) Trans_Time FROM CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
                            DECLARE @time_beetween_yesterday_and_today TIME = (SELECT CAST((@datetime_access - @yesterday_last_datetime_access_checked) AS TIME(0)))
                            DECLARE @time_to_int INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, @time_beetween_yesterday_and_today))
                            DECLARE @total_minutes TIME = (DATEADD(MINUTE, (@time_to_int), ('00:00')))
                            INSERT INTO Attendance (payroll_id, tag, date_attendance, total_time) VALUES (
                                @payroll_id, @tag, @today_date, @total_minutes
                            )
                        END
                END
            END
            

    END
```

Si simulo los datos de la tabla si es funcional e inserta en la otra tabla por eso deduzco que es algo en el trigger

```
DECLARE @CardAccessHistory  TABLE (
    Cardholder_ID INT,
    Card_Number VARCHAR(50),
    ACR_Name VARCHAR(60),
    Trans_Time DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @CardAccessHistory (Cardholder_ID, Card_Number, ACR_Name, Trans_Time) VALUES (372,'806768214','Entrada Torniquete 1','2021-11-03 11:10:55.000')

DECLARE @card_id INT = 372 --(SELECT Cardholder_ID FROM inserted)
DECLARE @datetime_access DATETIME = '2021-11-02 11:20:55.000' --(SELECT Trans_Time FROM inserted)
DECLARE @type_access VARCHAR(255) = 'Salida Torniquete 5' --(SELECT ACR_Name FROM inserted) 
DECLARE @payroll_id VARCHAR(20) = '1234' --(SELECT EmployeeNumber FROM CardHolders.dbo.Cardholders WHERE CardHolder_ID = @card_id)
DECLARE @tag VARCHAR(20) = '4321' --(SELECT Card_Number FROM inserted)
    IF @type_access LIKE '%Salida%'
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @total_time TIME = (SELECT total_time FROM Attendance WHERE payroll_id = @payroll_id AND CAST(date_attendance AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
            DECLARE @last_type_access_checked VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP (1) ACR_Name FROM @CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
            DECLARE @today_date DATE = (SELECT CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ))
            PRINT @last_type_access_checked
            IF @last_type_access_checked LIKE '%Entrada%'
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @last_datetime_access_checked DATETIME = (SELECT TOP(1) Trans_Time FROM @CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
                    DECLARE @add_minutes INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, (@last_datetime_access_checked), (@datetime_access)))
                    IF @total_time IS NULL
                        BEGIN
                            DECLARE @minutes_in_time_with_reset_total_time TIME = (DATEADD(MINUTE, (@add_minutes), ('00:00')))
                            INSERT INTO Attendance (payroll_id, tag, date_attendance, total_time) VALUES (
                                @payroll_id, @tag, @today_date, @minutes_in_time_with_reset_total_time
                            )
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            DECLARE @minutes_in_time TIME = (DATEADD(MINUTE, (@add_minutes), (@total_time)))
                            UPDATE Attendance SET total_time = @minutes_in_time WHERE payroll_id = @payroll_id AND CAST(date_attendance AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
                        END
                    END
            ELSE IF @last_type_access_checked IS NULL
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @yestertday_last_type_access_checked VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP (1) ACR_Name FROM @CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
                    IF @yestertday_last_type_access_checked LIKE '%Entrada%'
                        BEGIN
                            DECLARE @yesterday_last_datetime_access_checked  DATETIME = (SELECT TOP(1) Trans_Time FROM @CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
                            DECLARE @time_beetween_yesterday_and_today TIME = (SELECT CAST((@datetime_access - @yesterday_last_datetime_access_checked) AS TIME(0)))
                            DECLARE @time_to_int INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, @time_beetween_yesterday_and_today))
                            DECLARE @total_minutes TIME = (DATEADD(MINUTE, (@time_to_int), ('00:00')))
                            INSERT INTO Attendance (payroll_id, tag, date_attendance, total_time) VALUES (
                                @payroll_id, @tag, @today_date, @total_minutes
                            )
                        END
                END
            END
```

Comment: la lógica que implementaste en tu trigger solo funcionaría si siempre se inserta solo 1 fila a la vez, es ese el caso?

Comment: Si es una sola fila a la vez, el problema viene cuando meto ciertas condiciones (IF) inserta datos en una fila a la vez dependiendo de las condiciones, pense... sera la logica pero la logica del trigger ya la probe y funciona,

Comment: tendríamos que ver cuál es la lógica al momento de insertar filas en la tabla principal

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el motor sabe que @payRoll_id va a contener un solo valor? Por otro lado, aunque solo reciba un valor el trigger (algo que quizá no debería), no sería mejor, que utilizases una sola select sobre inserted para alimentar todas las variables. `SELECT @card_id = Cardholder_ID, @datetime_access = Trans_Time
 , @type_access = ACR_Name , @tag= Card_Number FROM inserted; DECLARE @payroll_id VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT Top(1) EmployeeNumber FROM CardHolders.dbo.Cardholders WHERE CardHolder_ID = @card_id)`

Comment: Añadí la logica completa es un poco grande espero darme a entender, y en cuanto a @Javifer2 voy a intentar aunque las variables si traen un solo dato ya que si hago un insert a otra tabla pasando esas variables funciona, el detalle viene cuando meto condiciones

Comment: Incluso las variables que comentas simule sus datos y ejecute el trigger en un query normal y si es funcional toda la logica del Query es muy extraño

Comment: Si tienes un Sql Management Studio 17.9 o inferior, puedes trazar el código, poniendo la sentencia en una ventana para querys. Pones un punto de interrupción en la insert y pulsas Depurar (Alt+F5), Cuando arranca el depurador, vas paso a paso por instrucciones (F11). En la parte inferior, tienes una ventana de inmediato que te va mostrando los valores de las variables, y así puedes saber donde está el problema y lo que hace el trigger.

Comment: Añadi el query tal cual simulando los datos y es funcional en todas las condiciones y funciona sin ningun problema

Comment: Tienes un problema con tu tipo de datos. Los minutos no deben ir en tipo `TIME` porque después de 24 horas se reinicia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Cómo depurar un trigger? Requerido **Sql Management Studio 17.9** o inferior, porque en la versión 18.0 y superiores, se ha eliminado esta posibilidad.

[image: Depuración]

Pulsas sobre el icono de **Debug**. Cuando se ponga la linea en amarillo, pulsas **F11**

[image: Depurando 2]

Y puedes ir visualizando en la parte inferior la ventana de variables locales, que te dará información paso a paso sobre su contenido.

[image: Depurando 3]

Otra Opción Si no dispones de la herramienta, es ir plagando el trigger de mensajes para recoger información en la consola de salida.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterAccess] ON [dbo].[CardAccessHistory] AFTER INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'ENTRADA AL TRIGGER'
    DECLARE @card_id INT = (SELECT Cardholder_ID FROM inserted)
    PRINT CONCAT('@CARD_ID VALOR ',CAST(@CARD_id AS VARCHAR(30)));
    DECLARE @datetime_access DATETIME = (SELECT Trans_Time FROM inserted)
    PRINT CONCAT('@datetime_access VALOR ',CAST(@datetime_access AS VARCHAR(30)));
    DECLARE @type_access VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT ACR_Name FROM inserted) 
    PRINT CONCAT('@type_access VALOR ',CAST(@type_access AS VARCHAR(30)));
    DECLARE @payroll_id VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT EmployeeNumber FROM CardHolders.dbo.Cardholders WHERE CardHolder_ID = @card_id)
    PRINT CONCAT('@payroll_id VALOR ',CAST(@payroll_id AS VARCHAR(30)));
    DECLARE @tag VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT Card_Number FROM inserted)
    PRINT CONCAT('@tag VALOR ',CAST(@tag AS VARCHAR(30)));

    IF @type_access LIKE '%Salida%'
        BEGIN
            PRINT CONCAT('@type_access VALOR ',CAST(@type_access AS VARCHAR(255)));

            DECLARE @total_time TIME = (SELECT total_time FROM Attendance WHERE payroll_id = @payroll_id AND CAST(date_attendance AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
            DECLARE @last_type_access_checked VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP (1) ACR_Name FROM CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
            DECLARE @today_date DATE = (SELECT CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ))
            IF @last_type_access_checked LIKE '%Entrada%'
                BEGIN
                    PRINT CONCAT('@last_type_access_checked VALOR ',CAST(@last_type_access_checked AS VARCHAR(255)));
                    DECLARE @last_datetime_access_checked DATETIME = (SELECT TOP(1) Trans_Time FROM CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
                    DECLARE @add_minutes INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, (@last_datetime_access_checked), (@datetime_access)))
                    IF @total_time IS NULL
                        BEGIN
                        PRINT '@total_time VALOR IS NULL';
                            DECLARE @minutes_in_time_with_reset_total_time TIME = (DATEADD(MINUTE, (@add_minutes), ('00:00')))
                            INSERT INTO Attendance (payroll_id, tag, date_attendance, total_time) VALUES (
                                @payroll_id, @tag, @today_date, @minutes_in_time_with_reset_total_time
                            )
                        PRINT CONCAT('@minutes_in_time_with_reset_total_time VALOR ',CAST(@minutes_in_time_with_reset_total_time AS VARCHAR(255)));
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            PRINT '@total_time VALOR IS NOT NULL'
                            DECLARE @minutes_in_time TIME = (DATEADD(MINUTE, (@add_minutes), (@total_time)))
                            PRINT CONCAT('@minutes_in_time VALOR ',CAST(@minutes_in_time AS VARCHAR(255)));
                            UPDATE Attendance SET total_time = @minutes_in_time WHERE payroll_id = @payroll_id AND CAST(date_attendance AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
                        END
                    END
            ELSE IF @last_type_access_checked IS NULL
                BEGIN
                PRINT '@last_type_access_checked VALOR IS NULL'
                    DECLARE @yestertday_last_type_access_checked VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP (1) ACR_Name FROM CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
                    IF @yestertday_last_type_access_checked LIKE '%Entrada%'
                        BEGIN
                            PRINT CONCAT('@yestertday_last_type_access_checked VALOR ',CAST(@yestertday_last_type_access_checked AS VARCHAR(255)));
                            DECLARE @yesterday_last_datetime_access_checked  DATETIME = (SELECT TOP(1) Trans_Time FROM CardAccessHistory WHERE Cardholder_ID = @card_id AND CAST(Trans_Time AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Trans_Time DESC)
                            PRINT CONCAT('@yesterday_last_datetime_access_checked VALOR ',CAST(@yesterday_last_datetime_access_checked AS VARCHAR(255)));
                            DECLARE @time_beetween_yesterday_and_today TIME = (SELECT CAST((@datetime_access - @yesterday_last_datetime_access_checked) AS TIME(0)))
                            PRINT CONCAT('@time_beetween_yesterday_and_today VALOR ',CAST(@time_beetween_yesterday_and_today AS VARCHAR(255)));
                            DECLARE @time_to_int INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, @time_beetween_yesterday_and_today))
                            PRINT CONCAT('@time_to_int VALOR ',CAST(@time_to_int AS VARCHAR(255)));
                            DECLARE @total_minutes TIME = (DATEADD(MINUTE, (@time_to_int), ('00:00')))
                            PRINT CONCAT('@total_minutes VALOR ',CAST(@total_minutes AS VARCHAR(255)));
                            
                            INSERT INTO Attendance (payroll_id, tag, date_attendance, total_time) VALUES (
                                @payroll_id, @tag, @today_date, @total_minutes
                            )
                            PRINT 'AFTER INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE'
                        END
                END
            END
            
    PRINT 'END TRIGGER'
    END
```

Luego ejecutas una sentencia de inserción y miras por donde ha pasado.